# GZIPInputStream.read(...), is reading less number of bytes than supplied length parameter

Tags: java, zip, compression, gzip, gzipinputstream

I have a .gz file which I'm trying to read using `GZIPInputStream`, fixed number of bytes at a time.
I am using `GZIPInputStream.read(byte[] buf, int off, int len)` (ref: [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-)) to do this.
But the method is reading only 397 bytes(return value of the above method) when the length supplied is 490.

It didn't throw any exception.

I'm wondering in which cases will the return value of the method be less than the supplied length parameter.

What I understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551685/java-gzipinputstream-read-function) question is that some of bytes we want to read might be in the next chunk(which is not uncompressed yet) and we might want to read again (not sure whether this is correct interpretation though).
But the documentation of the GZIPInputStream.read(...) doesn't talk about any such chunking.

I uncompressed the .gz file manually and tried reading the uncompressed file using `RandomAccessFile.readFully(byte[] b)` (ref: [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readFully-byte:A-)), which reads all 490 bytes properly.

I'm expecting the GZIPInputStream.read(...) method also to read all 490 bytes properly.

Comment: Your question is moot.  The spec of `read` does not say that the method will fill the supplied buffer (if possible) so your code shouldn't rely on that happening.  Your expectation (last paragraph) is INCORRECT.

Comment: And the answer to "when" it will return less than the number of bytes that you expect is - that will depend on the implementation ... and it might change from one version to the next.

Comment: @StephenC, I'm not expecting my byte array to be filled, but I'm expecting return value = supplied len value. i.e; the method reads said no. of bytes

Comment: That's what I mean.  The javadoc does not say that you will get `len` bytes.  Or even that you will get `len` bytes if there are `len` bytes left in the (inflated) stream.  All it guarantees is that you won't get zero bytes!  Read the javadocs carefully.

Comment: Furthermore, why do you care? A properly written copy loop doesn't care how many actual bytes were read on each iteration. `while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, count); }`. Same for any other read loop: take account of the actual value returned by `read()`, and don't make any assumptions about it.

Comment: @user207421 Because, I'm not decompressing the file. I'm just trying to read it and the format is in such a way that each line is prefixed by a header which contains size of the line. Is this the wrong way? Should I be decompressing the file first?

Comment: @StephenC I see. Sounds like I'm using this stream for the wrong use case here.

Comment: You *are* decompressing the file, because you're using `GZIPInputStream`., and you can't possibly get to see your line headers *unless* you decompress the file. Make up your mind. In any case it is immaterial. Take proper account of the value returned by `read()` and you should not have a problem.

Comment: @user207421 Sure. By "not decompressing", I mean, I'm not looking to create a separate file which is the decompressed version of the .gz file I have.

Comment: Irrelevant, *Whatever* you do with the buffer you provided to `read()`, it is invalid to process it beyond the count returned by `read()`. There is no basis anywhere for your expectation.

Comment: @user207421 I see that "len" is "the maximum number of bytes read" and there is no guarantee as to how many bytes will be read. I'll change my code to deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  That's what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question in the reverse order that you asked it.

> I'm expecting the `GZIPInputStream.read(...)` method also to read all 490 bytes properly.

While you may expect this, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html#read-byte:A-int-int-) for `read(buf, off, len)` does not state that that will happen.  What it actually says is this:

> *"Reads uncompressed data into an array of bytes. If `len` is not zero, the method will block until some input can be decompressed; otherwise, no bytes are read and 0 is returned.*
>
> *Returns: the actual number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the compressed input stream is reached."*

It does NOT state ANYWHERE that `read` will return as many (available) bytes as will fit.

So, basically, it is your *expectation* that is wrong.  You shouldn't write code that assumes that `read` will "properly" read all 490 bytes in one call.

---

> I'm wondering in which cases will the return value of the method be less than the supplied length parameter.

The code is complicated.  It will be reading from the underlying stream in blocks.  Then, when it inflates a stream, it may turn turning a small number of compressed bytes into a large number of uncompressed bytes.  So, the `InflaterInputStream` layer has to deal with cases where advancing the input by one byte results in ... more bytes that will fit in the remainder of the user's buffer.

So (to my mind) it is unsurprising that they would take the simple (and efficient) approach of not entirely fill up the buffer, leaving the unconsumed (compressed) bytes for the next `read` call<sup>1</sup>.

And then there are mysterious "GZIP trailer members" which are dealt with at the `GZIPInputStream` layer.

Like I said ... it is complicated.

In short, there could be a number of cases where you may not get a number of bytes equal to `len`.  But it won't *help* you to know all of the details.  Especially since they *could* depend on what version of Java you use!

What you need to know is that is it incorrect for your code to *assume* that it will get all of the bytes available in a single `read` call.  Even if the byte buffer that you provide is big enough.  You already have evidence that that assumption is incorrect.

<sup>1 - Though it does have to deal with that scenario in the pathological case where you call `read` with `len == 1`.</sup>

---

> Sounds like I'm using this stream for the wrong use case here.

No.  The use-case is fine.  The problem is that your code is using the `GZIPInputStream.read` method incorrectly.

For what it is worth, this `read` method is behaving roughly the same way as a `read` on a `SocketInputStream` would behave if the "other end" of the socket was writing sporadically.  It gives you what is available *now*.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I see that "len" is "the maximum number of bytes read" and there is no guarantee as to how many bytes will be read. I'll change my code to deal with this. Thanks!

Comment: Correct.  That's what it means.